# Input field text, changes styling only on IOS

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, input

i have an issue where the text inside my input field looks like this, but only on IOS. And when i start typing in the field, all is okey..

[image: image of problem]

it looks okey, on android and desktop´, only ios seems to cause issues.

Any tips for resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

code:

html:

```
<div class="search-overlay">
        <div class="search-input" role="search">
            <input placeholder="Søg på titel" name="query" data-quick-search="" id="search-programs-input"
                type="text" class="" value="" autocomplete="off"><button type="submit" class="dr-icon-search search-input-icon form-control-feedback"><span class="sr-only">{{dictionary "search" "Title"}}</span></button>
            <button type="button" class="close close-search" data-quicksearch-close=""><span class="dr-icon-close" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">{{dictionary "mainNavigation" "closeSearch"}}</span></button>

        </div>
    </div>
```

styling:

```
.search-overlay {
    background-color: white;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -75px;
    width: 500px;
    right: 5px;
    z-index: 900;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    .search-input {
        padding: 15px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        input {
            background: #E5E5E5;
            width: 92%;
            font-size: 24px;
        }
        button {
            border: none;
            background: transparent;
            &[class*=dr-icon-search] {
                position: absolute;
                right: 55px;
                top: 23px;
                &:before {
                    font-size: 25px;
                    color: gray;
                }
            }
            .dr-icon-close {
                position: absolute;
                right: 14px;
                top: 23px;
                &:before {
                    font-size: 15px;
                    color: gray;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You'll need to include your code for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: @MateBoy it has now been added.

Comment: no one can think of a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

adding `Line-height:24px;` to my input fixed the issue...